# Why are permissions hijacked by Features module?

Tags: 6, features

Trying to understand what exactly I have done here.

I have made a Feature to export CCK config. I added `CCK: content` to it for a bunch of content types, and so it contains auto-detected dependencies for about 10 modules including Node, Fieldgroup and Date. I put the resulting Feature in code and it seems to work as expected as a deployment tool for CCK.

What I don't understand:

- On the dev server, the Permissions pages shows all my node-related permissions (`create example content` etc.) under `node module`
- On the production server, the Permissions pages shows these same permissions under `features module`

What is happening and how can I get the config back into symmetry?

Comment: Have you enabled the feature you created on your dev server?

Comment: Yes. Enabled on both.